# How to get MFCC with TarsosDSP?

Tags: android, mfcc, tarsosdsp

I searched everywhere and I couldn't figure out how to extract MFCC feature using TarsosDSP on Android. I know how to get FFT out of a file.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See official [github page](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/e9bb33dbe8f6678c32b0344f4367ceb383220748/src/tests/be/tarsos/dsp/test/MFCCTest.java)

**MFCC Test file**

```
public class MFCCTest {

//  private static int counter = 0;

    @Test
    public void MFCCForSineTest() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException{
        int sampleRate = 44100;
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferOverlap = 128;
        final float[] floatBuffer = TestUtilities.audioBufferSine();
        final AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromFloatArray(floatBuffer, sampleRate, bufferSize, bufferOverlap);
        final MFCC mfcc = new MFCC(bufferSize, sampleRate, 40, 50, 300, 3000);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mfcc);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioProcessor() {

            @Override
            public void processingFinished() {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        dispatcher.run();
    }

}
```

and TestUtilities audioBufferSine()

```
public class TestUtilities {

    /**
     * Constructs and returns a buffer of a two seconds long pure sine of 440Hz
     * sampled at 44.1kHz.
     * 
     * @return A buffer of a two seconds long pure sine (440Hz) sampled at
     *         44.1kHz.
     */
    public static float[] audioBufferSine() {
        final double sampleRate = 44100.0;
        final double f0 = 440.0;
        final double amplitudeF0 = 0.5;
        final double seconds = 4.0;
        final float[] buffer = new float[(int) (seconds * sampleRate)];
        for (int sample = 0; sample < buffer.length; sample++) {
            final double time = sample / sampleRate;
            buffer[sample] = (float) (amplitudeF0 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f0 * time));
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the mfcc under the process event, i think that it is for each frame

```
    int sampleRate = 16000;
    int bufferSize = 512;
    int bufferOverlap = 128;
    new AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this);
    final List<float[]>mfccList = new ArrayList<>(200);
    InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(audioFilePath);
   AudioDispatcher dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(new UniversalAudioInputStream(inStream, new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(sampleRate, bufferSize, 1, true, true)), bufferSize, bufferOverlap);
    final MFCC mfcc = new MFCC(bufferSize, sampleRate, 20, 50, 300, 3000);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mfcc);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void processingFinished() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
            mfccList.add( mfcc.getMFCC());
            return true;
        }
    });
    dispatcher.run();
```

Comment: How can I get mfcc from [audiorecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) data?