# How do you extract MFCC data from file using TarsosDSP?

Tags: java, android, audio, mfcc, tarsosdsp

I created an MFCC extraction portion of my code based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436075/how-to-get-mfcc-with-tarsosdsp) on Stack Overflow, which created two `AudioProcessor` instances. However, using the debugger on Android studio, I found that the code quickly enters the `processingFinished` function while it skipped the process function for both. The `mfcc` variable in the instance was left null during the `processingFinished` function of the second AudioProcessor function. Why does the data never process? Is this the right way to get the MFCC?

My source code: (I changed theAudioDispatcher to pipe from file)

```
private void onMFCC() {

    int sampleRate = 44100;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int bufferOverlap = 128;
    //final AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,512);
    String path = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/saytest.mp4";
    new AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this);
    final AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(path, sampleRate, bufferSize, bufferOverlap);
    final MFCC mfcc = new MFCC(bufferSize, sampleRate, 40, 50, 300, 3000);

    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mfcc);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void processingFinished() {

            //vvv error b/c mfcc instance variable is null
            //float[] mfccArr = mfcc.getMFCC();  
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
            // breakpoint or logging to console doesn't enter function
            return true;
        }
    });
    dispatcher.run();

}
```

Is there is a possibility that an error because of the pipe AudioDispatcher had to do with this?

```
Starting piped decoding process for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.audiorecorder/cache/saytest.mp4
I/PipeDecoder:  with command: "/data/user/0/com.example.audiorecorder/cache/ffmpeg" -ss 0.0   -i "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.audiorecorder/cache/saytest.mp4" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -sample_fmt s16 -f s16le pipe:1
I/PipeDecoder: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/com.example.audiorecorder/cache/ffmpeg": /data/data/com.example.audiorecorder/cache/ffmpeg: has text relocations
I/PipeDecoder: Aborted 
I/PipeDecoder: Finished piped decoding process
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**
I tried calling the process function independently by adding this line to the end of the method:

```
mfcc.process(new AudioEvent(new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(sampleRate, bufferSize, 1, true, true)));
```

However, this gave me a NullPointerException.

- I also compared the mfcc instances using two different audio files but I found that they had the exact same data, so they had no results from processing. When I changed the dispatcher back to the microphone, the mfcc had a value and the program went through the process function! Why doesn't it work for the dispatcher accessing an audio file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue because I realized that the dispatcher `fromPipe` wasn't working, so I replaced the dispatcher:

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(path);
AudioDispatcher dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(new UniversalAudioInputStream(inStream, new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(sampleRate, bufferSize, 1, true, true)), bufferSize, bufferOverlap);
```